# Android App which will reply to the incoming msg automatically

Tags: android

I am creating an Android App which will reply to the incoming msg automatically. I am using a Dual Sim Phone, how can i identify to which the message is sent to.

Answer (score 1):

By default the message will be sent by SIM 1

you can check it by using getSimOperator() it will returns the MCC+MNC (mobile country code + mobile network code) of the provider of the SIM.
or you can also use String getSimSerialNumber() to get the sim serial number

more function here ->[TelephonyManager](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/telephony/TelephonyManager.html)

don't forget to add READ_PHONE_STATE permission

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
    TelephonyManager phoneManager = (TelephonyManager) 
          getApplicationContext().getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
    String phoneNumber = phoneManager.getLine1Number();
```

This requires READ_PHONE_STATE permission.